# Hide Parameters in web.show_document() when passing from ORACLE FORM to REPORT

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms, oraclereports

I am new to racle forms and report generation, I have successfully created a report by using the following syntax

```
web.show_document('http://URL/reports/rwservlet?KEY1&report=reportpage.rdf&destype=cache&desformat=pdf&paramform=no&server=rsnic'||'&transid='|| FS_TEMP || '&user_parameter=' || 'User_data','_blank');
```

The issue is that when I generate the Report the above link comes in the Browser URL so if anyone changes the "User_data" the report gets changed.

Is there anyway I can hide the User Parameter and its value

Answer (score 0):

To secure the call to web.show_document you first need to make use of the RUN_REPORT_OBJECT.

The Oracle White Paper [Integrating Oracle Reports in Oracle Forms Services applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/frm10gsrw10g-132606.pdf) states:

> The most secure approach for calling Reports from Forms on theWeb is
>   to use the Oracle Application Server 10g reports Services in
>   combination with RUN_ REPORT_OBJECT. Because the user’s database
>   connection is implicitly passed from Forms to Reports on the server,
>   there is no risk of interception as if it were passed in a URL.

From page 10 this same document explains with an example on how to use RUN_REPORT_OBJECT.